# Spring batch access data from internal tables

Tags: spring-batch

Spring Batch core framework is using following tables (on screenshot). Is it possible somehow to get data from those tables, for example to expose this data with an API. Or somehow reference this data programmatically.  Or those table are internals of Spring Batch and not supposed to be used directly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These tables are not intended to be modified by the user, except in one case where a job has been killed and should be restarted (in this case, the job execution status should be updated manually in the table, you can find more details about this in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#aborting-a-job)).

> Is it possible somehow to get data from those tables, for example to expose this data with an API. Or somehow reference this data programmatically

The `JobExplorer` API is what you need. It is a read-only version of the `JobRepository` and allows you to access those tables programmatically.